# MPVolumeView stealing touches from adjacent UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

[image]

I have several UIButtons gathered around an MPVolumeView. The bottom right one frequently won't respond to touches, only when the MPVolumeView has 'user interaction enabled'. It's only that button and no others. If I disable user interaction on the volume view, the button responds fine. Sometimes the button will work fine however. It seems to happen completely at random. I made the background of both views red, and it's obvious they're not overlapping with each other. This is for my iPhone XIB. My iPad XIB is layed out in pretty much the same fashion, just with larger buttons, and it does not have this problem.

So I started logging touches using the method [here](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/monitoring-all-ios-touches/) and what I'm seeing is that MPVolumeView is stealing those touches.

`touchesBegan: (
    "<UITouch: 0x1659e5a0> phase: Began tap count: 1 window: <UIWindow: 0x1656f590; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1656a770>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1656cf20>> view: <MPVolumeView: 0x1655cd10; frame = (66 64; 176 29); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1655ce80>> location in window: {63, 408.5} previous location in window: {63, 408.5} location in view: {215.5, 12} previous location in view: {215.5, 12}"
)`

One those rare occasions that the button actually does receive the touch, the log looks like this:

`touchesBegan: (
    "<UITouch: 0x1799d2d0> phase: Began tap count: 1 window: <UIWindow: 0x1656f590; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1656a770>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1656cf20>> view: <UIButton: 0x16561b70; frame = (254 55; 50 50); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; tag = 3; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16512410>; layer = <CALayer: 0x165f3990>> location in window: {60, 420} previous location in window: {60, 420} location in view: {39, 24} previous location in view: {39, 24}"
)`

I'm confused! Can anyone tell me what could be causing this?